# Hover over image breaks it html

Tags: html, image, hover, mouseover

When I mouse over the image, it displays the broken image symbol and doesn't revert when I move my mouse out. Here is my HTML:

```
<img src="images\News\btn_DownloadNow.png" onmouseover="this.src='over_DownloadNow.png'" onmouseout="this.src='btn_DownloadNow.png'">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your image is in the correct file path. Perhaps it's in `images\News\`? If it is, you would have to write it the way Flaudre recommended. Or it could be your slashes. Maybe use forward slashes instead? `images/News/`.

Comment: You're right, it needed forward slashes! Thank you!

Comment: No problem! Glad you were able to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<img src="images\News\btn_DownloadNow.png" onmouseover="this.src='images\News\over_DownloadNow.png'" onmouseout="this.src='images\News\btn_DownloadNow.png'">
```

Comment: Hm, it does work fine for me. Are you sure the file over_DownloadNow.png is located in the News folder? Is it possible that the file is broken or maybe a jpg and not a png? Anyway you may also consider using css to do hover effects! Because as soon as you have multiple buttons it's easier to assign them to a common css class than to define each onmouseout and onmouseover property of every element using js.

Comment: Strange.. yes its located in the same folder as btn_DownloadNow.png, and I just double checked they are both .png files. But thanks anyway...

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

`<img onmouseover="this.src='over_DownloadNow.png';" onmouseout="this.src='images\News\btn_DownloadNow.png';" src="images\News\btn_DownloadNow.png" alt="">`

Comment: still didn't fix it :( i've tried in both chrome and firefox and its still the same issue